# how to remove three dots from UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a UILabel that contains text that is bigger than the label size. (The UILabel has 2 lines.)

The UILabel is showing the three dots (ellipsis) on iOS. I do not want label to show this dots. How can I make them not show?

Comment: Do you want to resize to fitting its text?

Comment: no . about  
Do you want to resize to fitting its text? label size is constant

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set the label's `lineBreakMode` to `.ByClipping`(Swift) or `NSLineBreakByClipping`(Objective-C).

Comment: when label text
"text 1 text 2 text 3 text 4  \n \n \n \n \n \n"
in this case when first line is"text 1 text 2 text 3"
there are still 3 dots after "text 4 " on second line . In other cases like for same label uses text"text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1" It can help

Comment: i fix it by adding space character " " var theLabelTextString = "text 1 text 1 text 1 text 1"
        for iter in 0...20
        {
            theLabelTextString += " "
        }

Comment: using both lineBreakMode and  many space character  " "  before  \n \n \n \n \n \n solved my case . thanks

Comment: You can also do this in Interface Builder's UILabel settings. Set **Line Breaks** to **Clip**

Answer (score 6):

Programmatically,

nameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping

Answer (score 1):

Please add code

```
[labelname sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have achieved by following steps:**

1.Increase height of label as I did so that 2 lines fit.

2.select label, go to `attributes inspector`

3.select `Line Breaks` = `Word Wrap`

4.also increase lines, like 2,3

[image: changing line break in attributes inspector]
changing line break in attributes inspector

**Worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fit the size or show the three dots, you need to set your label like this.

Objective-C

```
[label setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByClipping];
```

Swift

```
label.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
```